# Express multer is returning undefined on req.file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, multer

I am trying to pass a file to node and express will not store it in req.body so I am using the multer middleware but I am getting undefined whenever I log req.file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

react/index.js

```
fileSelectHandler = e => {
  axios.post("/api/upload", { profilePic: e.target.files[0] });
  this.setState({ profilePic: e.target.files[0] });
};

render() {
  return (
    <input
      onChange={event => this.fileSelectHandler(event)}
      name="profilePic"
      type="file"
    />
  );
}
```

node/index.js

```
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("profilePic"), (req, res) =>
  console.log(req.file)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for uploading the file instead.

```
fileSelectHandler = e => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const profilePic = e.target.files[0];

  formData.append("profilePic", profilePic);

  axios.post("/api/upload", formData);
  this.setState({ profilePic });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to upload your file as a Form Data type as follow.

```
fileSelectHandler = e => {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append(‘profilePic’,e.target.files[0]);

const config = {
    headers:{
        ‘content-type’:’multipart/form-data’
        }
    }
axios.post("/api/upload", formData, config);
this.setState({ profilePic: e.target.files[0] });
};
```

Hope it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Another example for multiple files input. Tested on Express JS

```
function uploadImages(post) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        for( var i = 0; i < post.length; i++ ){
            formData.append('multifiles', post[i]);
        }
        let jsonPost = {
            method: POST_REQUEST,
            url: UPLOAD_FILE_URL,
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            }
        };
        fetchData(jsonPost)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("RESULT uploadImages: ", res.data);
                resolve(res.data);
            })
            .catch(reject);
    });
}
```